# Create image captcha with PHP

Tags: php, captcha

Hi i want to create a image captcha with [php](/questions/tagged/php), i have the next code for my form.

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <div class="label_form">Usuario:</div> <input type="text" name="user"/><br>
    <div class="label_form">Contraseña:</div> <input type="password" name="pass"/><br>  
    <img alt="Numeros aleatorios" src="layouts/captcha.php" />  
    <input class="label_form" type="text" name="num"/><br>
    <input type="submit" value="ENTRAR" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

This is the code for validation before to send the form:

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
  if ($_SESSION['img_number'] != $_POST['num']) {
    echo "<div class='msg_error'>Los caracteres no se corresponden.</div>";
  } else {
    /*DO STUFF*/
  }
}
```

And in other file with the name `captcha.php` i have the code [php](/questions/tagged/php)for generate the image:

```
header("Content-type: image/png");
$string = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
  $pos = rand(0, 36);
  $str. = $string {
    $pos
  };
}
$img_handle = ImageCreate(60, 22) or die("Es imposible crear la imagen");
$back_color = ImageColorAllocate($img_handle, 102, 102, 153);
$txt_color = ImageColorAllocate($img_handle, 255, 255, 255);
ImageString($img_handle, 31, 5, 0, $str, $txt_color);
Imagepng($img_handle);
session_start();
$_SESSION['img_number'] = $str;
```

This give a image broken showing the alt from `img` `"Numeros aleatorios"`, so that tell me the `file.php` is calling fine the `img` but the code for generated is not working, any help is gratefull :D thanks.

Comment: If this is for educational purposes they this is fine, however if your wanting to use this in production I will warn you against it. Bots have become very good a reading images to crack captcha systems. I would recommend looking at googles recaptcha or search google for another captcha generator.

Comment: so you think is fine use something like this $im = imagecreatefrompng("prueba.png"); for gnerate in base from image already exist or definitely use other method?

Comment: The amount of effort to make it secure against bots would not be worth the time. I would recommend using a 3rd party like recaptcha for it.

Comment: ok yes is right,, i wiill leave the question active, because i dont understand why not working, but your suggest is usefull i will use other method to do this thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is good the only thing you missed is declaring `$str = ""` at the top of your `catpcha.php` file

Here is a working capture of your code:

[image]

### Update

Your `$string` length is 36, so you should generate a random position between 0 and 35, like this:

```
$pos = rand(0,35);
```

If not, you sometimes get a broken image and a PHP Notice.

### Update N°2

The reason why you get a broken image without declaring `$str = ""` is because this line

```
$str .= $string{$pos};
```

Throws a `PHP` Notice and corrupts the image. (Of course only if you *display_errors* , that's why it worked perfectly for @Danny's server)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing:

```
$str .= $string{$pos};
```

to

```
$str .= $string[$pos]; //Array of strings.
```

I've updated my answer:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: image/png");
$string = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"; 
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) { 
    $pos = rand(0,36); 
    $str .= $string[$pos]; 
}
$img_handle = ImageCreate (60, 22) or die ("Es imposible crear la imagen"); 
$back_color = ImageColorAllocate($img_handle,102,102,153); 
$txt_color = ImageColorAllocate($img_handle,255,255,255); 
ImageString($img_handle, 31, 5, 0, $str, $txt_color); 
Imagepng($img_handle); 
session_start(); 
$_SESSION['img_number'] = $str;
?>
```

In my local server the captcha image is showing properly.

[image: In my local server the captcha image is showing properly.]

Comment: Is still not showing the image, only the broke img :/

Comment: Make sure about the GD Library in your PHP.

Make sure about the GD Library in your PHP. I've implemented your code and it runs correctly.

http://dfjb.webcindario.com/captcha.php

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez if GD wasn't installed code would die **"Es imposible crear la imagen"**. Check my answer to see why this works in your test server..

Comment: However, my code still works properly displaying the image on my test server.

Comment: Yes, it does indeed work. And it would work in his own server if he sets `display_errors` to `false`. But it's a good practise to solve problems, not to hide them. PS: your code will not work when the `rand(0, 36)` returns `36`. You'll probably get just 4 characters instead of 5 in the captcha.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a screenshot with my same version of my answer.